Retain rights on files created by another user
A slightly simplified version of my situation:
On a Windows machine (Server 2016), I have a folder (c:\myfolders\user1Folder), which is owned by User1.
User2 has full access to this folder, and creates a file here (c:\myfolders\user1Folder\MyFile.txt). Now User2 owns this file and User1 can't access it...
How does one config things so that if User2 creates a file in this folder, User1 has full access?

All access to a file is defined through its ACL ("Access Control List") which you can see in the Security tab of the file's Properties dialog. Any user or group you add to the ACL with e.g. Full control access will indeed have Full control access.
Ownership is almost irrelevant, as the only actual access it grants is the ability to reset the access list if it gets messed up.  Even for the owner, all other access (read, write, delete, etc) is only gained through being explicitly listed in the ACL.
(You'll notice that some folders have a special "CREATOR OWNER" entry in their access list – whenever a new file is created and inherits the access list, this entry expands to an entry for the new file's actual owner, and that is how users are given access to files they own.)
So if you want to grant access to newly created files, open the folder's access list via 'Properties' → 'Security' → 'Advanced' and add an "inheritable" entry that would explicitly give the necessary access to User1. Use the Advanced view for this, and make sure the entry is marked as "Applies to: This folder, subfolders, and files". It's possible that the folder already has an entry for User1 but only a non-inheritable one; if so, add a new one anyway.
C:\> icacls c:\myfolders\user1Folder /grant "User1:(OI)(CI)(F)"

(OI) = object inherit (files)
(CI) = container inherit (subfolders)
(F) = access flags "Full control"

If this doesn't work as it should, examine the ACL of those newly created files and check whether they're set to inherit permissions from parent at all. Some programs deliberately create files with restricted, non-inheritable ACLs (e.g. ssh-keygen does so when creating private key files; and Cygwin in particular tends to set non-inheritable permissions to mach POSIX style) and in those cases you can't override that through file ACLs – by design – except by patching the program or using icacls /reset to re-enable inheritance.

If it does work, consider whether you need "Full control" (F), or whether just "Modify" (M) would be enough. (Full control also gives User1 the ability to change ACLs as if they were the owner, or in fact even to take ownership for themselves, basically 99% co-ownership. But sometimes one might not want other editors to be able to mess with ACLs, in which case Modify is sufficient.)
Also, consider whether it would be better to add a group to the access list instead. Groups need to be created by an admin, but they make it easier to keep multiple separate folders' access lists in sync whenever a person needs to be added or removed.
